# How to change the value of a variable once per day in Java/javascript

Tags: java, javascript, calendar

I'm trying to make an application/script for my school which displays the day's schedule. The catch with this is that my school runs on an 8 day cycle, so that complicates things. I have a a variable called  *cycleDay* , but how would I go about updating this just once per day, and not more than that? If there's another way you can think of doing this, please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: if you explain more about `cycleDay` i can give you complete code

Comment: Just to be sure, Java is NOT Javascript. Are you using one or the other, or somehow integrating the two together?

Comment: I'm clear that there's a difference. Ideally, I wanted to make sure that the code works in Java before I transpose it over to javascript for the website. I've tried using a while loop, but the problem with that is that it constantly updates the `cycleDay` variable until the date becomes either a weekend or a holiday, in which case the while condition would be set to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, say, the `getTime()` function of the `Date` object, which returns the current time in milliseconds after January 1, 1970 (source: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp), and save that value (e.g. in `var lastUpdateTime`). Then periodically check if the difference between the current time and that saved time is more than a day. If so, update *cycleDay*, and also update `lastUpdateTime` to the time when you updated.

For instance, initialize with:

```
var lastUpdateTime = new Date().getTime();
```

Somewhere else in your code:

```
var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
if(currentTime - lastUpdateTime >= 24*60*60*1000) // number of milliseconds in a day
{
    // update cycleDay
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: @nondeterminstic narwhal How would `currentTime` differ from `lastUpdateTime` unless there is legitimately a 24 hour difference between the two variables?

Comment: Presumably you would set `lastUpdateTime` somewhere, and then later on call the `currentTime` part periodically or on some event - user clicks a button to update schedule or user accesses the page, and the second part of the code gets called, and if that happens 24 hours later variable is updated etc. ... I don't know how the rest of your program functions so I didn't put more details.

Comment: @nondeterminstic narwhal The second part sounds good to me. Ideally, when the user accesses the page, that's when I would call `currentTime` so it updates in that sense. Another way I thought of was just hardcoding `lastUpdateTime` so that it was a date like, let's say, today. Then, use something similar to the logic you used above. Thoughts on that?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Apologies for delay; I wasn't sure if you had resolved your issue or not. Did you get your code to work? If you found a working solution, be sure to accept whichever answer on this page helped the most with your problem. If you haven't resolved it already, just take a stab at the problem in the way you described above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Date` and `document.cookies` to update your variable. Also i used two utility methods to manipulate `document.cookies`

```
var today = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/(1000*3600*24))

var cookies = getCookies();

if(cookies["last_updated"] && cookies["last_updated"]<today) 
{
    /* update variable */
    setCookie("last_updated", today, 1);

}

/* utility methods starts, adding utility methods to simplify setting and getting    cookies  */
function setCookie(name, value, daysToLive) {
   var cookie = name + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
   if (typeof daysToLive === "number")
      cookie += "; max-age=" + (daysToLive*60*60*24);
   document.cookie = cookie;
 }

function getCookies() {
    var cookies = {}; // The object we will return
    var all = document.cookie; // Get all cookies in one big string
    if (all === "") // If the property is the empty string
       return cookies; // return an empty object
    var list = all.split("; "); // Split into individual name=value pairs
    for(var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) { // For each cookie
       var cookie = list[i];
       var p = cookie.indexOf("="); // Find the first = sign
       var name = cookie.substring(0,p); // Get cookie name
       var value = cookie.substring(p+1); // Get cookie value
       value = decodeURIComponent(value); // Decode the value
       cookies[name] = value; // Store name and value in object
  }
  return cookies;
}
/* utility methods ends */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private Date lastUpdate = now()-1;
private myDailyChahgedValue;

Integer getMyDailyChangedValue() {
 if (lastUpdate <> now()) {
  myDailyChahgedValue ++;
}

return value;

}
```

Please note it is an a draft of code what shows main idea

Comment: @Joel: It's a different user number :P