# How to change the value of a variable every day?

Tags: javascript, function, date

I have developed a javascript code on how to change the value of a variable every day. I am not sure if it is correct. Please do check and let me know if I can improve it.

```
       var y = 5; 
       var x = 3;

       var data = new Date(2017,3,1)       
       var updatedData = Date.now();
       var difference = updatedData - data;
       var milliSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
       if (difference >= milliSeconds){
                var z = parseInt(y) + x;
                console.log(z);
                data = updatedData;
       }
```

Comment: by doing this clientside, it means your browser has to be open everyday and all day

Comment: why hardcoded date in data? and difference is always going to be `>=` and what is the purpose of parsing an int value to int again?

Comment: parseInt(y) is y ,also data after first log will be set to Date.now() and all the process will stop

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the value of a variable once per day in Java/javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17753666/how-to-change-the-value-of-a-variable-once-per-day-in-java-javascript)

Comment: This is not a code review site, it's for answering specific questions. You have not provided any criteria for what might be considered improvements, so it's also opinion based.

Answer (score -1):

Use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) function

 I do not test, try this, it's may work

```
var nIntervId;
var data;
var milliSeconds = (now to midnight);


function changeValue() {

  if(milliSeconds < (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) ){
    milliSeconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
    stopInterval();
    createInterval();
  }
  // change data value
  data =  Date.now();

}


function createInterval() {
  nIntervId = setInterval(changeValue, milliSeconds);
}

function stopInterval() {
  clearInterval(nIntervId);
}
```

Comment: this will execute 86400 times in each day. which means, the user have to create a bot to click on the `ok` of alert automatically.

Comment: you must precalculate milli seconds, 1000 is just for example